# Merging IMAP account into gmail

Tags: gmail, imap, pop3

I have a university email account which provides access only via IMAP and webmail, and which does not provide a usable email forwarding service. Is there any way of getting emails from this account automatically downloaded to my gmail? The only thing I could think of would be to set up my own POP server to shadow the IMAP server, and then use gmail's POP downloader.  This seems a bit baroque, and I was wondering if anyone knows of a more straightforward alternative.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It will take awhile depending on how many messages you have and how big, but you can set your gmail account to allow an imap connection and connect to both with an application like Thunderbird and simply drag your mail from one to the other. Once you have the two set up, you can setup a filter rule that will move new mail each time you connect.
[Enabling IMAP in Gmail](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=77695)

Comment: that's what I did :)

Answer (score 4):

imapsync worked fine for me ...

```
    imapsync \
    --host1 "${from_host}" --user1 "${from_login}" --password1 "${from_passwd}" \
    --ssl1 \
    --host2 "${to_host}" --user2 "${to_login}" --password2 "${to_passwd}" \
--ssl2 \
    --authuser1 "${from_login}" --authmech1 LOGIN \
    --authmech2 LOGIN \
    --syncinternaldates   --useheader 'Message-Id'  --skipsize --allowsizemismatch
```

http://imapsync.lamiral.info

imapsync is still floss, available at https://github.com/imapsync

Comment: Can you expand your answer? Remember, we are here to act as the professionals, and not everyone will just know what that product is or how to use it

Comment: If IMAP isn't enabled on your source host, http://davmail.sourceforge.net is very easy to use to proxy your email through.